# How to show focus on image onclick of it in android?

Tags: android, focus, android-imageview

How can i show the focus over an image when the image is clicked? 
I just want to show focus when the user is clicking it (to let the the user know that he has clicked it). And image should appear normal when the user lifts his finger. Can anyone guide me? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set imageView onTuch event and in onTuch event setFocusable() true and false in up and Down Event.

imageView.setFocusable(true) or imageView.setFocusable(false);

Comment: setfocusable() does nothing. I'am changing background color on ACTION DOWN

Answer (score 1):

create selector for image view...........

```
 <selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/....." />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/......" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/......" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/....." />
</selector>
```

and make android:clickable="true" or iv.setclickable(true);